# user/password for app-deployer and adapter-deployer ANT tasks?

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

Deploying to application center using com.ibm.appcenter.ant.UploadApps requires a user/password; however I see no such parameters for app-deployer and adapter-deployer tasks.  Is this intentional?

I've used the app-deployer and adapter-deployer successfully in development, but I also have never locked down my WL console... when I go there, I'm automatically logged in as 'guest'.  If/when I secure the WL Console and force admins to log in, will the app-deployer and adapter-deployer start failing or do those somehow bypass that security?

**April 24, 2013 update:**

I attempted to deploy to a secure server and got the following error, even when I tried to pass user password on the URL:

> Error message:  [app-deployer] Apr 24, 2013 2:06:08 PM
>   com.worklight.ant.deployers.AbstractDeployerTask logDeployResponse
>   [app-deployer] SEVERE: Can't access the Worklight Server. If you
>   protected the Worklight Console, remove the protection first.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, as long as we're not talking about HTTPS, it should be in the vein of `http://username:password@serverAddress:port/contextRoot`

Comment: Thanks Idan!  I'll give this a try once I secure the WL server.

Comment: Any news? Is this question answered?

Comment: I finally tried this out.  Here's the error I'm getting when I attempt with to deploy to a secure WL server ... I even tried with passing the user/password on the URL.  Error message:  [app-deployer] Apr 24, 2013 2:06:08 PM com.worklight.ant.deployers.AbstractDeployerTask logDeployResponse
[app-deployer] SEVERE: Can't access the Worklight Server. If you protected the Worklight Console, remove the protection
first.

Total time: 1 minute 32 seconds

Comment: But is it HTTP or HTTPS? if it's HTTP rather than HTTPS, then it is simply not possible for either, as long as the console is protected.

Comment: It's http that I'm testing with.  Just noticed that in this other thread, you said it's not possible on 5.0.5 at all:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952319/worklight-ant-task-app-deployer-unauthorized-error-when-wl-console-security-is?rq=1 .  I'm a little confused ... under what scenario you'd expect this to work: http://username:password@serverAddress:port/contextRoot ?

Comment: I guess I was mistaken. It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

On WL 6.1.0.2, you can now do this and pass the username password of the worklight console for the app and adapter deployment.

```
<app-deployer deployable="${basedir}/bin/${app.name}-all.wlapp"
worklightServerHost="${resolved.worklight.server.url}" 
userName="${worklight.server.user}"     
password="${worklight.server.password}" />

<adapter-deployer deployable="${basedir}/bin/OSLCGenericAdapter.adapter"
worklightserverhost="${resolved.worklight.server.url}" 
userName="${worklight.server.user}"     
password="${worklight.server.password}"/>
```